# extracting required data from a plot

Tags: python, plot, curve-fitting

if I plot the following yearly population data on x and y axis's respectively, how do I obtain the daily data from the plot for the 10 years, Like I want to be able to obtain the population for every day from the curve that is created using this data

is that possible?

```
    2020    713,000 
    2019    703,000 
    2018    694,000 
    2017    684,000 
    2016    674,000 
    2015    664,000 
    2014    655,000 
    2013    645,000 
    2012    636,000 
    2011    627,000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import pandas as pd

# make your data a frame
df = pd.DataFrame([[2020,    713000], 
[    2019,    703000], 
[    2018,    694000], 
[    2017,    684000], 
[    2016,    674000], 
[    2015,    664000], 
[    2014,    655000], 
[    2013,    645000], 
[    2012,    636000], 
[    2011,    627000]], columns=['DateTime','pop'])

# make DateTime column an datetime object
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime(x,1,1))

# create a time range for each day in your period
time_range = np.arange(datetime(2011, 1,1), datetime(2021,1,1), timedelta(days=1))

# make time_range a frame 
af = pd.DataFrame(time_range, columns=['DateTime'])

# merge both together (left join on column DateTime) and interpolate the gaps
df = af.merge(df, on='DateTime', how='left').interpolate()

print(df)
```

Comment: thanks a lot , you really saved a ton of my time